# how do you transfer contacts and pictures to an SD card

Tags: storage, sd-card

I cant download any apps because of family setup and now I have to restart my phone. How can I save all of my information to my SD card.

Comment: I assume you mean "reset" your phone?

Answer (score 1):

Your contacts data will be saved to your Microsoft account so you don't need to backup it (it is not possible to save the data to the SD card anyway). Verify if your data synched properly on outlook.com.